# Clarification in finding a polynomial equation with roots that are related to the roots of another polynomial equation by a particular function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Consider a polynomial equation $p(x)=0$ the solutions to which are $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ (where $p$ is a polynomial function from $\mathbb{C} $ to $\mathbb{C}$). If I wanted to find another polynomial equation q(y)=0 whose solutions are $f(x_1),f(x_2),...,f(x_n)$ for $f:\mathbb{C}  \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, then I would use the substitution $y=f(x) \implies x=f^{-1}(y)$ and substitute this into the original equation which I would then rearrange to get the desired polynomial equation. But what about cases like $y=x^2$ where $f$ is not bijective unless we restrict it's domain? Up until now I have always just written $x=y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and rearranged to get the desired equation but wouldn't $x=-y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ be just as valid? I tried an exercise of this style using $x=-y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and got the correct equation.

I would like to understand why both substitutions seem to work the same in getting to the correct final equation. Will this method work generally regardless of the fact that $f$ has different inverses for different parts of this domain. Will this ever cause problems?

Comment: Why not just use $q(y)=(y-f(x_1))(y-f(x_2))\cdots (y-f(x_n))$?

Comment: @Randall This method is often simpler, and is also one that I've been taught so ideally I would like to understand it.

Comment: The only irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb C[x]$ are the linear one (because $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what about cases like $y=x^2$ where $f$ is not bijective unless we restrict it's domain? 
> Up until now I have always just written $x=y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and rearranged to get the desired equation but wouldn't $x=-y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ be just as valid?

Both are valid, and you would need both in general. For a simple example, consider:
$$
p(x) = x^2 - x - 2 = (x+1)(x-2)
$$

To find the equation(s) with roots $x_1^2, x_2^2$, substitute $y = x^2 \iff x = \pm \sqrt{y}$ with $y \ge 0$. This gives the following two equations to solve.

- $$y - \sqrt{y} - 2 = 0 \quad\iff\quad y = 4 \tag{1}$$
- $$y + \sqrt{y} - 2 = 0 \quad\iff\quad y = 1 \tag{2}$$

Neither one of the equations has the complete solution set of $\{1,4\}$. To get that, you need to effect *both* $x = \pm \sqrt{y}$ substitutions, solve the respective equations, then combine the solution sets.

> I tried an exercise of this style using $x=-y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ and got the correct equation.

What you did was probably take either one of the equations, move the square root to one side, then square the equation to eliminate the radical, so you ended up with $\,(y-2)^2 = y\,$. This *does* work, because it is in fact the same equation you'd get by multiplying $(1) \times (2)$:

$$
0 = \big((y - 2) - \sqrt{y}\big)\big((y - 2) + \sqrt{y}\big) = (y-2)^2 - y
$$

You can get the same equation without involving radicals in the process by using [polynomial resultants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant), which amounts to eliminating $x$ between the two algebraic equations $p(x)=0, y=x^2$ in order to obtain an algebraic equation in $y$. For the example here (courtesy [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28x%5E2+-+x+-+2%2C+x%5E2+-+y%2C+x%29)):
$$
\operatorname{res}_x\big(x^2 - x - 2, x^2 - y\big) = y^2 - 5 y + 4
$$

---

[ *EDIT* ] More generally, the same approach works with higher-order substitutions $y=x^m$ as well (though not necessarily with arbitrary non-bijective functions). In that case the left-inverse is $x = \omega^k \sqrt[m]{y}$ where $\sqrt[m]{y}$ is the principal value of the $m^{th}$ root, $\omega$ is a primitive $m^{th}$ root of unity, and $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, m-1\}$. This gives $m$ equations $f\big(\omega^k \sqrt[m]{y}\big) = 0$ for the $m$ different $k$. The union of their solution sets is $\{x_j^m \;\big|\; j = 1, 2, \dots, n\}$, and is the solution set of their product $g(y) = f\big(\sqrt[m]{y}\big) f\big(\omega \sqrt[m]{y}\big) \dots f\big(\omega^{m-1} \sqrt[m]{y}\big)$. From the definition, $g(x)$ is a symmetric polynomial in $\sqrt[m]{y}, \omega \sqrt[m]{y}, \ldots, \omega^{m-1} \sqrt[m]{y}$, so it can be expressed in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials in $\sqrt[m]{y}, \omega \sqrt[m]{y}, \ldots, \omega^{m-1} \sqrt[m]{y}$, which are the coefficients of $x^m - y$, in fact all $0$ except for the product which is $\pm y$. It follows that $g(y)$ is a real polynomial of degree $n$ which has $\{x_j^m \;\big|\; j = 1, 2, \dots, n\}$ as roots.

For example, using the same $p(x) = x^2 - x - 2$ as above, if $m = 3$ and $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity then (as verified in [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28a%5E2+-+a+-+2%29%28w%5E2+a%5E2+-+w+a+-+2%29%28w+a%5E2+-+w%5E2+a+-+2%29+where+w+%3D+%28-1+%2B+i+sqrt%283%29%29%2F2)):
$$
\begin{align}
g(y) &= \big(\sqrt[3]{y}^2 - \sqrt[3]{y} - 2\big)\big(\omega^2\sqrt[3]{y}^2 - \omega\sqrt[3]{y} - 2\big)\big(\omega\sqrt[3]{y}^2 - \omega^2\sqrt[3]{y} - 2\big)
\\ &= y^2 - 7 y - 8
\\ &= (y + 1)(y - 8)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Very insightful. I'm quite intrigued by the fact that rewriting the equation resulting from the substitution $x=\sqrt{y}$ to a polynomial equation is equivalent to multiplying the two equations resulting from the substitutions $x=\sqrt{y}$ and $x=-\sqrt{y}$ (In terms of obtaining the same final equation). Is there any way to understand this better or prove it? 
Also, I'd like to know if there is something similar going on when using $x=y^{1/3}$ in p(x)=0 to find the polynomial equation with complex solutions $x_1^3,x_2^3,...,x_n^3$ since in this case y will have 3 cube roots.

Comment: @CroW I added more details at the end, which hopefully answer the questions.